# SQLite database not inserting values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The project consists of two classes one is for the main activity and the another one is Database Helper class that extends Sqliteopenhelper class for executing query on database. The problem occurs when add data button doesn't inserts the data into the database. Probably, there is something wrong with the 'insert data' method, that I am unable to figure out. Or is it something else?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editName,editF1,editF2,editF3,editF4,editF5;
Button btnAddData;
Button btnViewAll;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
    editF1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_F1);
    editF2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_F2);
    editF3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_F3);
    editF4= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_F4);
    editF5= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_F5);
    btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    btnViewAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_viewAll);
    AddData();
    viewAll();
}   
public  void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = 
myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(), editF1.getText().toString(), 
editF2.getText().toString(), editF3.getText().toString(), 
editF4.getText().toString(), editF5.getText().toString() );
                    if(isInserted == true)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data 
Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not 
Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void viewAll() {
    btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                    if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                        // show message
                        showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
                        return;
                    }

                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        buffer.append("Name :"+ res.getString(0)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Teaching Skills :"+ 
res.getString(1)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Competency :"+ 
res.getString(2)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Approachability :"+ 
res.getString(3)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Class Control :"+ 
res.getString(4)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Punctuality :"+ 
res.getString(5)+"\n\n");
                    }

                    // Show all data
                    showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
                }
            }
    );
}

public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.dot.myapplication;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "F1";
public static final String COL_4 = "F2";
public static final String COL_5 = "F3";
public static final String COL_6 = "F4";
public static final String COL_7 = "F5";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (NAME TEXT,F1 TEXT,F2 TEXT,F3 
TEXT,F4 TEXT,F5 TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name,String F1s,String F2s,String 
F3s,String F4s,String F5s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,F1s);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,F2s);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,F3s);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,F4s);
    contentValues.put(COL_7,F5s);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
}
```

Whenever the add data button is clicked data not inserted toast gets invoked. Being a beginner I am unable to figure out where are the things going wrong. Is it something with the insertData method? Please suggest the changes.

Comment: Replace `insert` with `insertOrThrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insertion is correct. You have to query data like this.

```
             if(res.moveToFirst()){
                        do{
                            buffer.append("Name :"+ res.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Teaching Skills :"+ res.getString(1)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Competency :"+ res.getString(2)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Approachability :"+ res.getString(3)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Class Control :"+ res.getString(4)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Punctuality :"+ res.getString(5)+"\n\n");
                        }while (res.moveToNext()) 
             }
```

In your **Database** helper class, you forget to **close** the database after Querying it.

Here is a perfect tutorial to learn SQLite database implementation.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial